# CompositeCollection containing an ICollectionView

Tags: xaml, tabs

I'm trying to implement a tab control, where each item comes from an ICollectionView of my viewmodel. Each tab page, for the items from the ICollectionView will be the same. However, I would like there to be an extra tab page for configuration options.

So an example tab header 'screenshot' might be:

```
tabA | tabB | tabC | config
```

on another instance, it could be

```
tabA | config
```

or

```
config
```

I can define the header for each item using ItemTemplateSelectors, and the content using the ContentTemplateSelectors. So that bit should be okay.

I'm having trouble with adding the config page item since I do not know where to add it. I thought I could set the tab's ItemsSource to be a CompositeCollection, where the final item is the config page object. I have failed to achieve this.

In the following example, I can view the tab headers being populated correctly according to the designer sample data which I have set up - I have not yet added the config page.

```
        <controls:MetroTabControl ItemsSource="{Binding View}">
            <controls:MetroTabControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value.siteDisplayName}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </controls:MetroTabControl.ItemTemplate>
            <controls:MetroTabControl.ContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value.siteComment}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </controls:MetroTabControl.ContentTemplate>
        </controls:MetroTabControl>
```

As you see, I have set the ItemsSource to be {Binding View}. This "View" comes from my ViewModel and is an ICollectionView.

Ideally i'd be able to do some magic like:

```
        <controls:MetroTabControl>
            <controls:MetroTabControl.ItemsSource>
                <CompositeCollection>
                    <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding View}"/>
                    <SomeConfigPageObject/>
                </CompositeCollection>
            </controls:MetroTabControl.ItemsSource>
              ...snip...
        </controls:MetroTabControl>
```

But the problem is that when I do the above, the designer preview of the control acts as if there are no items in the ItemsSource.

For reference, each item in the {Binding View} is a object which contains a Value property, the value property containing an object that contains, in this example, a siteDisplayName and siteComment.

For reference, the DataContext for the tab is defined the dockpanel that contains it, as follows.

```
<DockPanel DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Configurator}}"
            d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance cfuid:ConfigSiteVMSampleData, IsDesignTimeCreatable=true}"
            LastChildFill="True">
```

For reference, the Configurator is my viewmodel and is instantiated in the xaml as:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        ...snip...
        <cfvmc:ConfigSiteVM x:Key="Configurator" />
        ...snip...
```

So, the actual question would be:
How do I add my "config page" at the end of the tab control? Preferably via using the above-hoped method of adding an extra config-page object on the CompositeCollection; however if this is not possible [1] i'm open for suggestions.

[1] I think it doesn't work because the {Binding View} is an ICollectionView and the CompositeCollection requires a "collection" and doesn't accept a "view"

Thank you.
Peter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to do it through code behind. This means that I do lose my ability to use the design-time data to preview my UI; but it works at run time.

So, in the xaml I have.

```
        <controls:MetroTabControl Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2"
                ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=ucMe, Path=TabSitesCollection}">
```

Where ucMe is the UserControl and TabSitesCollection is a

```
    protected CollectionViewSource m_TabSitesCollectionViewSource;
    protected CompositeCollection m_TabSitesComposites;
    public ICollectionView TabSitesCollection
    {
        get { return m_TabSitesCollectionViewSource.View; }
    }
```

That gets initialised in the constructor as follows

```
    public ConfigSiteView()
    {
        m_TabSitesComposites = new CompositeCollection();
        m_TabSitesCollectionViewSource = new CollectionViewSource();
        m_TabSitesCollectionViewSource.Source = m_TabSitesComposites;

        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

Then, on the Loaded event I can do

```
        m_TabSitesComposites.Add(new CollectionContainer() { Collection = GetModel.View });
        m_TabSitesComposites.Add(new TabItem() { Header = "hi" });
        m_TabSitesComposites.Add(new TabItem() { Header = "ho" });
```

This results in almost my desired UI
[image]

I now simply need to spiff up my settings tab item and i'm done.
For reference, the xaml designer does not have any preview data - Unless I change the xaml so that the preview loads up (which then breaks the actual execution)

It would have been nice to have it both work while running, and on preview, but I haven't figured out how to do that, and it's not a current priority.